# Domain and Range for a quadratic in a fraction

Tags: functions

What would the domains and the ranges be of functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Where $f(x) = {1\over (x-a)(x-b)}$ and $g(x) = {1\over (x+a)(x+b)}$

Comment: suggest picking specific values for $a,b$ maybe $a=1, b=3,$ then drawing $y = (x-a)(x-b)$ and $y = (x+a)(x+b)$ first. Then graph the reciprocals   http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: @Dan. Why did you unaccept my answer one day later ?  Do you need it to be more detailed ? Or is there something wrong with it ?  I'm only asking with the intention of learning/helping

Comment: @Shailesh I believe it may have been a glitch since I did not unaccept your answer.

Comment: @Dan. No worries. It's corrected somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline:

In the first case, the domain is clearly $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{a,b\}$. 
The range is $\{ y | y \gt 0$ or $y \le \frac{-4}{(a-b)^2} \}$.

This slightly wierd expression comes from $a - \frac{(a+b)}{2}$ and $b - \frac{(a+b)}{2}$.  (And $\frac{a+b}{2}$ in nothing but the vertex of the parabola of the quadratic)

I would encourage to take it from here. For $g(x)$, the argument is similar.